# Reboot does not clear "System restart required. Kernel SRU period has ended"

Tags: apt, upgrade, kernel

I have rebooted a few times since I started seeing this message  couple months ago but whenever I login I see the same message. I had a couple power outages this summer (before I bought a UPS) so that might have been the cause. What should I do to clear this message or should I ignore it? Thanks.

```
*** System restart required. Kernel SRU period has ended ***
```

This system is up-to-date.

```
0 updates can be applied immediately.
```

uname -a says I have this kernel:

```
Linux kvm 5.15.0-46-generic #49-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 4 18:03:25 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

This is on a 22.04.3 LTS system.

Comment: As I read it, you're using an outdated kernel (`linux-generic | 5.15.0.88.85           | jammy-security  | amd64, arm64, armhf, ppc64el, s390x`) and thus need to reboot and boot into the updated kernel to remove the message. You've possibly modified your `grub`  to favor this old outdated kernel, which has resulted in your not using a fully-patched system (*despite having applied them, you're not running them is my guess*) https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy-updates/linux-generic

Answer (score 4):

Do you have Ubuntu Pro enabled?

Running `pro status --all` shows in part:

```
NOTICES
The current kernel (6.2.0-1018-aws, x86_64) has reached the end of its livepatch support.
Supported kernels are listed here: https://ubuntu.com/security/livepatch/docs/kernels
Either switch to a supported kernel or `pro disable livepatch` to dismiss this warning.
```

You can disable this warning by running `pro disable livepatch`

For me, the curious thing is that my current kernel (6.2.0) is listed as [supported by livepatch](https://ubuntu.com/security/livepatch/docs/livepatch/reference/kernels) (as of writing). I think it has to do with [HWE vs GA kernels](https://ubuntu.com/security/livepatch/docs/livepatch/explanation/client_not_working).

Comment: Thank you, this was driving me nuts on my Azure VM. Good explanation.